# How to create playlists for my personal CD collection

Tags: music, playlists

I want to create playlists for my fairly large personal CD collection, augmented by other tracks and albums that I've retrieved from online. What is the best Ubuntu program for this purpose? I don't want to have anything to do with Apple stuff nor with Spotify. I would like to keep track of music that I've already played, never played, and favorites, as well as my own tree of categories.The programs I've seen such as Clementine all seem to be tied in with existing services and built-in lists.  It would also be helpful if the program included a manual.

Comment: Have you tried Rhythmbox? https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/Screenshots https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmbox

Comment: I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use VLC to play CD's. You can also use it to create a playlist. I would store the songs on the CD's on the hard drive or SSD.

Oliver Lau